# Object Reference error when getting directory in thread

Tags: c#, threadpool, .net

hi to all i am trying to get a access a folder in my thread like this

```
protected string GetFolderName(int OrgID)
{
    string FolderName = string.Empty;
    string[] strDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"));
    if (strDirectories.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < strDirectories.Length; count++)
        {
            string name = strDirectories[count].Substring(strDirectories[count].LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            if (name.Contains("_"))
            {
                string companyId = name.Substring(name.LastIndexOf("_") + 1);
                if (Convert.ToInt32(companyId) == OrgID)
                {
                    FolderName = name;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return FolderName;
}
```

This method is invoked through the thread pool and it's giving me an error of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on this line

```
string[] strDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"));
```

Please help me out

---

**Solution**

i used `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` in place of `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`HttpContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx) returns the current context *in the executing thread*. The thread pool thread isn't responsible for any HTTP request, so it doesn't have a context. The `Current` property will return null, which is why you're getting the exception. I suggest you call `Directory.GetDirectories()` *before* you transfer to the thread pool. An alternative would be to pass the context instead.

EDIT: If you don't want to perform `Directory.GetDirectories()` in the thread pool thread, you could at least evaluate `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/")` in the original thread, and make *that* available to the thread pool. Basically you just want to avoid evaluating `HttpContext.Current` on the wrong thread.

Comment: thanks for reply @Jon Skeet but i can't use Directory.GetDirectories()  before transfer to thread pool because i have to do some functionality in their and other operation like file.move also

Comment: @rahul: Why? That doesn't sound like a good reason to me. After all, it's basically the first thing you do in the thread pool thread - so why not do it just beforehand?

Comment: actually this is just a part of that thread pool original code is too long to paste here

Comment: @rahul: It would have been helpful if you could have explained that before. Well, yet *another* alternative is to evaluate `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/")` in the original thread, and pass *that* down to the thread pool thread. I'll edit my post.

Comment: yes i am doing the same thing now and i am using this HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath in place of Server.MapPath thanks for ur support

Answer (score 1):

Send `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/")` as the last parameter in `QueueUserWorkItem`